# Fill random values based on average and standard deviation of a range values in excel column

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Have been trying to write a macro to fill random values in the blank cells in each column based on Average and Standard deviation and within minimum and maximum values in the column range. '

Initially I tried to generate random values, however it is showing error "**this property or method is not supported.**"  Here is the code I tried

```vb
    Sub Insert_Random_Values()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim mean As Double
    Dim stdev As Double
    Dim rand As Double
    
    'Define the reference range
    Set rng = Range("A2:A11")
    
    'Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the reference range
    mean = WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
    stdev = WorksheetFunction.stdev(rng)
    
    'Loop through the cells in column B
    For Each cell In Range("B2:B11")
        'Check if the cell is empty
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            'Generate a random value with normal distribution
            rand = WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(WorksheetFunction.rand(), mean, stdev)
            'Check if the random value is less than 20
            Do While rand < 20
                'Generate another random value
                rand = WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(WorksheetFunction.rand(), mean, stdev)
            Loop
            'Assign the random value to the cell
            cell.Value = rand
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Sample table
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rnd` is used to generate a random single number.

Please ref to [Rnd function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461) .

```vb
    VBA.Randomize ' ** Initializes the random-number generator
    'Loop through the cells in column B
    For Each cell In Range("B2:B11")
        'Check if the cell is empty
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            ' ** Generate random number with Rnd
            rand = WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd, mean, stdev)
            'Check if the random value is less than 20
            Do While rand < 20
                'Generate another random value
                rand = WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd, mean, stdev)
            Loop
            'Assign the random value to the cell
            cell.Value = rand
        End If
    Next cell
```

Comment: This is generating random numbers for the cells in column B and replacing the original values.  I am looking to fill only blank cells with the random number.

Comment: Uncomment `If IsEmpty(cell) Then` to get what u r looking for.